# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS two wired networks not working

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, ethernet, gnome-control-center

I need to connect two wired ethernet segments to my 20.04 LTS desktop. One goes to a house private network of embedded systems I'm debugging; the other to the outside world. I added a second USB based ethernet adapter to it, and it almost configures right. *Almost.*  It seems I can have only one active at a time.  It won't let me enable both.  Turning on one turns the other off.

They aren't configured the same way.  The outside world is set up by the upstream ISP via DHCP; the other one is served by the desktop to the embedded boxes.

Is this `systemd` rearing its ugly head?  Because I end up turning on and off network settings often, I use Gnome's control panel for setup: `gnome-control-center network`  I'm guessing that it might be an easy change for a netplan guru but that isn't me.

Any ideas?  Wireless is *not* an option.

EDIT: `gnome-control-center` doesn't even reliably show me the two interfaces now.

EDIT 2: after dinking with /etc/netplan/*.yaml files and almost getting them to work, deleting everything in `gnome-control-center` and trying again, I was able to get it work as originally configured.  I guess that this is just an underutilized (and tested) code path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why my configuration now works.

The USB adapter could not be added unless there was a working network not connected to a USB device.  It was a happy accident that the internet was plugged in via USB, and it configured itself.

By contrast, I could add the built-in interface before a working box was ready to speak to the network.

I could not reasonably expect `gnome-control-center` to configure a new USB network interface in the reverse role.  (The embedded box doesn't show itself as aware of the network until the network is started on it, and Linux reports it as "Cablle disconnected.")

I consider that a **BUG**.